# Android - Crash when putting ArrayList in HashMap as value

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I want to store as value in hashMap an ArrayList. Here is my HashMap creation.

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashMap_undo;
```

In the method:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(name);
arrayList.add(score);
hashMap_undo.put("Color", arrayList);
```

after debugging, I found that the following line causes crash:

```
hashMap_undo.put("Color", arrayList);
```

"name" and "score" are both String values.

Please tell me if I forgot to include some information.

Comment: you have not initialised the hashmap

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar Oh I forgot that! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
  HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashMap_undo = new HashMap();
arrayList.add(name);
arrayList.add(score);
hashMap_undo.put("Color", arrayList);
```